# Why is example 1 not legal while example 2 is?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, extends

The following 2 snippets of code are from my textbook.

```
Secretary steve = new LegalSecretary();
steve.takeDictation("Hello!"); // OK
steve.fileLegalBriefs(); // compiler error


public class EmployeeMain4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee[] employees = {new Employee(), new Lawyer(),
        new Secretary(), new LegalSecretary()};

        // print information about each employee
        for (Employee e : employees) {
            System.out.print(e.getHours() + ", ");
            System.out.printf("$%.2f, ", e.getSalary());
            System.out.print(e.getVacationDays() + ", ");
            System.out.print(e.getVacationForm() + ", ");
            System.out.println(e); // calls toString
       }
    }
}
```

So as you can probably already tell, this question has to do with inheritance. I don't understand why you can create an array of objects whose classes were inherited from Employee, and use them to print out info without a cast. The first snippet of code clearly states that you need a cast to use the method that is existent in `LegalSecretary()`. Can someone please explain what is going on to me? Please do let me know if you need clarification on what my question is!

Comment: Please post `Secretary` and `LegalSecretary`. I have a pretty good assumption, where the problem lies, but i want to be sure.

Comment: Example 1 doesn't work because our boy Steve can't file his legal briefs. IE: The `Secretary` class has no method entitled `fileLegalBriefs()`.

Comment: @Tdorno i think it is the other way around: `LegalSecretary` has a method `fileLegalBriefs()`, but `Secretary` does not.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? I caught it and edited it after I submitted ha.

Comment: Why did people mark down this question? Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: @DhruvKhurana this is something you can read up on Google and is covered in each basic tutorial. Furthermore you did post incomplete code (see my first comment).

Comment: And follow-up question. If Secretary were to have the method fileLegalBriefs(), would the 3rd line of the first snipped be a valid piece of code?

Comment: @DhruvKhurana why don't you just try it out?

Comment: @Turing85 I told you that these methods are not in my textbook, they are just made up classes.

Comment: @DhruvKhurana if your text book covers inheritance, you should be able to write this methods by now.

Answer (score 3):

Well let's look at the info we're printing:

```
System.out.print(e.getHours() + ", ");
System.out.printf("$%.2f, ", e.getSalary());
System.out.print(e.getVacationDays() + ", ");
System.out.print(e.getVacationForm() + ", ");
System.out.println(e); // calls toString
```

All these methods exist in the base `Employee` class. They're overriden in each of the subclasses. When we call the method, if it's overriden in the subclass, the overriden method is called.

In the first example, we're calling `fileLegalBriefs()` on an object declared as a `Secretary`. The `Secretary` class doesn't have that method, so it's an error, even though the object is actually a `LegalSecretary`, which has it.

Comment: This is partway there. You also need to mention how `fileLegalBriefs` is a member of `LegalSecretary` but not `Secretary` (if I understand the class names correctly)

Comment: Is that better? Sorry I hit submit before adding the second part :P

Comment: Yep, the answer is complete now.

Comment: And follow-up question. If Secretary were to have the method fileLegalBriefs(), would the 3rd line of the first snipped be a valid piece of code? @hexafraction

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't call methods from `Employee` on an instance of `Secretary` or `LegalSecretary` there wouldn't be any point of inheritance! This is what inheritance means - the methods of a parent class are inherited by the child class.

In the first example, `LegalSecretary` is the child class and `Secretary` is the parent class. You can't call `fileLegalBriefs()` on an instance of `Secretary` because the method is defined in `LegalSecretary` and a parent does not inherit from its child.

Comment: And follow-up question. If Secretary were to have the method fileLegalBriefs(), would the 3rd line of the first snipped be a valid piece of code?

Comment: @DhruvKhurana Yes it would be.